# Quick Sort: Mutable or ST Array

Tags: haskell, quick-sort

This is the most Monadic code I have written to date :-) and I'd welcome comments.

I'm also struck how much faster this mutable approach is than the immutable version I first wrote (see end). OK, so QuickSort is pretty much on mutability, but most algorithms seems to involve significant manipulation of elements in the data structure and immutability leads to slowness due to the endless copying of e.g. Arrays.  I'm left wondering whether immutability is practical in the real world?

```
-- qsort :: Array -> beginning of subsection -> end of subsection
qsort :: (IOArray Int Int) -> Int -> Int -> IO ()
qsort arr min mx =
    if mx - min < 1 then do
        return ()

    else do
        p <- readArray arr min
        --foldM :: Monad m => (a -> b -> m a) -> a -> [b] -> m a
        final_i <- foldM (partitioner p) (min+1) [(min+1)..mx]
        swap min $ final_i - 1
        qsort arr min     (final_i-2)
        qsort arr final_i mx     

    where
        swap i j = do
            arr_i <- readArray arr i
            arr_j <- readArray arr j
            writeArray arr i arr_j
            writeArray arr j arr_i

        partitioner p i idx = do
            arr_idx <- readArray arr idx
            if arr_idx > p then
                return i
            else do
                swap i idx
                return $ i+1
```

I have since made the minor modifications to use an ST Monad ([Gist](https://gist.github.com/simonh1000/d0f6a17e5e862c19cb33)). Not sure which is to be considered better Haskell though.

```
qsort :: (V.Vector Int) -> Int -> Int -> (V.Vector Int)
qsort v i j
    | len < 2 = v
    | j > len - 1 = 
        let
            -- should really switch pivot with last point in < group
            --swap 0 (i-1)
            (less, greater) = V.splitAt i v
            less_sorted = qsort (V.tail less) 1 1
            great_sorted = qsort greater 1 1
        in less_sorted V.++ cons (V.head less) great_sorted
    | vector_j > p = 
        qsort v i (j + 1)
    | otherwise = 
        qsort (swap i j) (i+1) (j+1)
    where
        len = V.length v
        p = v ! 0
        vector_i = v ! i
        vector_j = v ! j
        swap i' j' = update v $ fromList [(i', v!j),(j', v!i)]
```

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review.

Comment: Could you perhaps also share the immutable version?

Answer (score 2):

## Mutability, ST and pure code

Whenever you can use `ST` instead of `IO` use `ST`. `ST` limits the effects that can happen, and `runST` (or its variants) make sure that no `STRef`s (or variants) leave the `ST`. That is, you can always embed a `ST s a` where you want to use `a`. You cannot do the same for `IO a`.

Unfortunately, `update` has \$\mathcal O(n+m) \$, and therefore every call of `swap` is \$\mathcal O(n) \$. That's not a problem when you have a single `Vector`, e.g.

```
V.foldr (\x a -> x + 2 * a) 0 . V.map sin . (// foo) . fromList
```

will generate a *single* vector due to fusion, not three intermediates. Depending on the used `vector` version and optimization level, you might even end up with a single loop and no generated vector at all. So immutability doesn't prevent optimizations.

Quick Sort on the other hand really *needs* mutability. So a `ST` variant (`STUArray` or [`MVector`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed-Mutable.html)) is more appropriate.

## Interface

Now that we know that it's fine to use an `ST` variant, let's have a look at your code. First we look at `qsort`'s type:

```
qsort :: (IOArray Int Int) -> Int -> Int -> IO ()
```

An end user has no idea what `Int` and `Int` shall be. They want to sort an array, not ponder the right arguments. Therefore, we add a variant that doesn't use that arguments:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Mutable as M

sort  :: Ord a => V.Vector a -> V.Vector a
sort v = -- left as exercise, should use sort'

sort' :: Ord a => M.STVector s a -> ST s ()
sort' v = qsort v 1 (M.length v)
```

This interface is easy to use and hard to get wrong. I use the `vector` variants since I'm more familiar with those, but the same holds for `STArray`. Note that I relaxed the `Int` to Ord a => a`.

## Internals

Next, we have a look at `qsort` itself. I'll keep its type for now. First of, instead of

```
if condition then return () else action
```

use

```
when (not condition) action
```

After all, `return` does not return prematurely, which can be misleading to Haskell newcomers. Next, try not to shadow `Prelude` names like `min` and `max`. Let's call the arguments `lower` and `upper` instead.

Furthermore, you call the value at an index `arr_idx`. That's misleading. And `p` is usually used as predicate, so let's call it `piv` instead. And `final_i` is just the new `midpoint` we found with our `piv`. We end up with.

```
qsort :: Ord a => (IOArray Int a) -> Int -> Int -> IO ()
qsort arr lower upper =
    when (upper - lower >= 1) $ do
        piv <- readArray arr lower
        midpoint <- foldM (partitioner p) (lower+1) [(lower+1)..upper]
        swap lower $ midpoint - 1
        qsort arr lower   (midpoint - 2)
        qsort arr final_i upper
    where
        swap i j = do
            arr_i <- readArray arr i
            arr_j <- readArray arr j
            writeArray arr i arr_j
            writeArray arr j arr_i

        partitioner piv i idx = do
            value <- readArray arr idx
            if value > piv then
                return i
            else do
                swap i idx
                return $ i+1
```

**Exercise:** Try to rewrite `qsort` with `M.Vector` or even `Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable` (the latter only needs an additional constraint).

## Bottom line

Other than that your mutable code looks fine. I would change `swap` slightly so that there is only one temporary element, though:

```
        swap i j = do
            tmp <- readArray arr i
            readArray arr j >>= writeArray arr i
            writeArray arr j tmp
```

That's personal preference.